# How can I iterate through a column of a spark dataframe and access the values in it one by one?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have spark dataframe
[Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEsTW.png)

I would like to fetch the values of a column one by one and need to assign it to some variable?How can it be done in pyspark.Sorry I am a newbie to spark as well as stackoverflow.Please forgive the lack of clarity in question

Comment: For which column you want to do this?

Comment: There are some fundamental misunderstandings here about how spark dataframes work. Don't think about iterating through values one by one- instead think about operating on all the values at the same time (after all, it's a parallel, distributed architecture). This seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please explain, in detail, what you are trying to do and try to [edit] your question to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples).

Comment: Also, [don't post pictures of or links to code/data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 4):

```
col1=df.select(df.column_of_df).collect()
list1=[str(i[0]) for i in col1]
#after this we can iterate through list (list1 in this case)
```

Comment: What if there are more number of rows? `collect()` operation will be costly right?

Comment: repartition the dataframe to the same number of nodes, the instance is running on, before using collect() to reduce time and memory costs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you are asking, but if you want to store them in a variable outside of the dataframes that spark offers, the best option is to select the column you want and store it as a panda series (if they are not a lot, because your memory is limited).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

var = df.select(F.col('column_you_want')).toPandas()
```

Then you can iterate on it like a normal pandas series.

Comment: No ,I need to access one value in each iteration and store it in a variable.I dont want to use toPandas as it consumes more memory!